# Quicktime logo! Can it be hidden / disabled?

Tags: video, quicktime

just wondering if it is possible to hide/disable the quicktime logo when displaying .MOV video on my site?

Because the size of the video is large (3MB), I have included a rotating loading animation, however once the video player loads, the Quicktime logo hides the animation, which makes the user less likely in my opinion to wait for the movie to load?

Any advice would be great!

Cheers!
Decbrad

Answer (score 0):

Yepp

Name=showlogo, value=false

If you use the QT_WriteOBJECT you should use 'showlogo','false'