# How to remove quicktime logo from loading video at ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, css, quicktime

I am implementing my own HTML5 video control to play mp4 videos inside. It works fine at all browsers instead of my destination iPhone OS 4.3 Safari. When i am trying to load new video into my control QuickTime logo appears. And disappears when video was loaded onto device. it takes only few seconds but unfortunately such behavior breaks all my stylish design.

[image: quicktime logo at loading HTML5 video]

Is there any chance using JS or HTML, CSS to remove it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quicktime logo! Can it be hidden / disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798361/quicktime-logo-can-it-be-hidden-disabled)

Comment: good catch. but the only answer there is to use showlogo = false. But where i can use this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `showlogo` attribute in the `EMBED` or `OBJECT` tags.

For an embed it is:

```
<embed src="foo.mov" qtsrc="hi.mov" width="320" height="240" showlogo="false">
```

Put in an object it takes the form:

```
<param name="showlogo" value="false" >
```

You can find more info on [HTML Scripting Guide for QuickTime](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html) on Apple.com.